# How to count collisions in a list of strings in Java

Tags: java, string, hashmap, hashcode

How may I count all pairs of collisions in a list of Strings using hashcode of each string?

```
public class HashCollisions {
private static int strLength;
private static int colls;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] strings ={"AaAaAa","AaAaBB","AaBBAa","AaBBBB"};

    strLength=strings.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < strLength - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < strLength; j++) {
            if (hash(strings[i]) == hash(strings[j]) && !(strings[i].equals(strings[j]))) {
                    colls++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(colls);

}

private static byte hash(String s) {
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    byte result = bytes[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        result ^= bytes[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

- With the given input I should detect the count of the pairs of collisions: 
  {0=[AaAaBB, AaBBAa], 32=[AaAaAa, AaBBBB]} which will be 2 .
- Any other solution more efficient than O(n^2)?

Comment: By collisions you mean strings with same hashcode?

Comment: Please do not clarify in a comment, but edit the question instead.

Comment: BTW `new HashMap<String>()` should be `new HashMap<>()` or `new HashMap<Integer, Set<String>>()`, you can't just set one generic type and leave others, either set all of them or use diamond operator to let compiler infer it.

Comment: Are all strings are guaranteed to be unique? If not what results would you expect for list containing `"foo" "foo" "foo" "foo"`?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to help if you post example of input and expected results with explanation why such result is expected but possible others would be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks
I added the example input and expected output

Comment: Your previous code should work fine. It grouped all strings with same hash in sets. What I don't quite understand is what you mean by "number of collisions". Do you want to get amount of elements with same hashcode? Or maybe amount of pairs which can be build from elements with same hashcodes?

Comment: @Pshemo right! I want number of elements with the same hashcode :)

Comment: In that case just iterate over sets (map values) and check which contain more than 1 element. Iteration can look like `for (Set<String> set : map.values()){...set.size();...}` but you can also use streams. If you don't want to preserve strings with same hash but just want to count them you can use `Map<Integer, Long> countedHashes = listStr.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::hashCode, Collectors.counting())); /*now lets eliminate hashes which are unique*/ countedHashes.values().removeIf(amount -> amount == 1);`.

Comment: @Pshemo
I edited mu question. Your solution doesn't give the right output. Could you please take a look on updated example?

Comment: What would be right output? What you get instead?

Comment: Here is updated demo https://ideone.com/LAXhHb.

Comment: @Pshemo Many thanks for your updated demo. I should have mentioned this point that I need to count all pairs of collisions

Comment: I am confused. I asked you specifically earlier "Do you want to get amount of elements with same hashcode? Or maybe amount of pairs which can be build from elements with same hashcodes?" and you said amount of elements, not pairs... So which is it? We can't help you if we don't know what you want specifically. So again, post example of possible input (and maybe explain what input would be impossible, like if elements must be unique or not), expected result, logic explaining why such result is expected and why potential others would be wrong.

Comment: @Pshemo You're right! That's my fault. I've just updated the question with input and expected output. The expected result is the number of the pairs of collisions.

Comment: Lets say that in map we will get `hash1={a,b},hash2={c,d,e},hash3={f,g,h}, hash4={i,j}`. What should be expected result? Should it be 4 because there are 4 separate hashes which appeared more than once? Or maybe something else?

Comment: @Pshemo No, the expected result is counts of just pairs (double entry) the following: {hash1=(a,b) , hash2=(c,d), hash2=(d,e)} which would be 3

Comment: Then what you are looking for is probably `countedHashes.keySet().size()` (based on what I already posted in linked demo).

Comment: @Pshemo but this one just gets size of map entries and each entry may have more than two strings

Comment: Oh, missed fact that hash2 appeared twice as key, which is impossible for map since keys should be unique. But in that case why there is no `hash2=(c,e)` pair in expected result?

Comment: @Pshemo Many thanks for your help. I resolved the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the list of strings by their `hashCode` and then work with the resulting map. As soon as you have more than one value for a given key there is 
 a collision:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "AaAa", "foobar",
            "BBBB", "AaBB", "FB", "Ea", "foo");
    Map<Integer, List<String>> stringsByHash = strings.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::hashCode));
    for (Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : stringsByHash.entrySet()) {
        List<String> value = entry.getValue();
        int collisions = value.size() - 1;
        if (collisions > 0) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Got " + collisions + " collision(s) for strings "
                            + value + " (hash: " + entry.getKey() + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Got 1 collision(s) for strings [foo, foo] (hash: 101574)
Got 1 collision(s) for strings [FB, Ea] (hash: 2236)
Got 2 collision(s) for strings [AaAa, BBBB, AaBB] (hash: 2031744)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use a Set, put every value in your List into the Set, and find the number of collisions by calculating List.size() - Set.size()?

Comment: I need to find the collision of hashcodes for each string

Comment: This will only give the number of duplicate strings.  Does nothing with collisions.

Comment: I get the duplicates using 
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(listStr);